# How can I nuke/format/erase Windows while it's running?

Tags: windows, windows-8

I need to nuke a Windows 8 tablet before I have to hand it back. I loaded a bunch of junk on, and we don't want the manufacturer poking around with our VPN client, Citrix Receiver, etc all installed.

**I went to do a factory reset**, but that's asking for a Windows 8 install CD or USB. The tablet doesn't have a USB input that I can use, and I really don't want to set up networking booting just to wipe this thing.

I tried popping open a command prompt using psexec running under a system context and running `format c:`, it says the drive is in use.

#### How can I nuke/format/erase, or otherwise obliterate a running install of Windows, without the use of a DVD-R or USB?

Comment: No USB? What tablet model is that?

Comment: @Tanner: If you run `reagentc.exe /info`, what does it show under the  path to recovery image?

Comment: Windows 8 has a "Reset" feature suggest using that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Erase all traces of Windows 8](http://superuser.com/questions/613577/erase-all-traces-of-windows-8)

Comment: Why is this a bad question?

Comment: I tried a factory reset. It's asking for a DVD. The situation is a bit more complicate than "there is no USB", but more, "I don't have a USB slot available, __period.__" I realize this is a bit of a weird/contrived sounding situation, but it's not the first time I've wanted to nuke a live install of Windows _from_ Windows, so I thought I'd ask...

Answer (score 2):

You can't, as far as I know. Modifying a running kernel takes something like Ksplice (which I'm pretty sure doesn't exist for Windows, or people wouldn't complain so much about rebooting for updates). You could, however, use something like [SDelete](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897443.aspx) to delete any sensitive files and then zero the free space.

However, if you just want to wipe the memory (and it's a standard x86 machine), you could put [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/) on a USB stick and run that.

EDIT: noticed you said no USB input - you will have to find some way to boot a different OS if you want to securely erase the entire system.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned this is a Windows 8 machine, you should be able to do this:

```
Windows-C to bring up the Charms
Settings
Change PC Settings
Update and Recovery
Advanced Startup
TroubleShoot
Advanced Options
Command Prompt
```

You will have to logon, however you will be booted from an in-memory recovery version of Windows.

After that, you should be able to run

```
diskpart
select disk 0
list volumes
```

You should then be able to select the windows volume and delete it.  Note -- there is no way of going back from this if you change your mind.

There may be a more non-destructive way to do this too... like perhaps resetting the PC to factory settings, which should be an option under the 'Update and Recovery' settings.